# Check Unique Column Values Based on Combination of other Column Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to be able to check if one column always has a unique set in the other columns. For example, in this dataframe, I would like to test if Orange always has a value of yes, yes in stale and stock and apple always has a value of yes, no. Please give me instructions on how to do this for a larger dataframe in order to check if one volumn is mapped form the unique combination of another two columns.

```
type    stale    stock      
orange    yes     yes    
apple     yes     no     
orange    yes     yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove all duplicate rows (based on relevant columns) from the df, then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on type and check that `size()` is equal to `1`.

try this:

```py
print(df.drop_duplicates(['type', 'stale', 'stock']).groupby('type').size().eq(1))
```

Output:

```
type
apple     True
orange    True
dtype: bool
```

and here's a bigger example with some values that also don't have a unique set:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """
type    stale    stock      
orange    yes     yes    
apple     yes     no     
orange    yes     yes
orange    yes     yes
banana    yes     yes
banana    yes     no
peach     no      no
peach     yes     no
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep="\s+")

print(df.drop_duplicates(['type', 'stale', 'stock']).groupby('type').size().eq(1))
```

Output:

```
type
apple      True
banana    False
orange     True
peach     False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer. What about if i wanted to print all the unique stale and stock values for each type. For example: Apple would give me (yes, no) and orange would give me (yes, yes) banana would give me (yes yes) and (yes no).

Comment: @ezra just remove everything after the ". size", groupby will do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are looking to find that out for all of the values existing in your dataframe or if it's just for a single given value for example if you want to do that for "orange" you could use this :

```
df.loc[df["type"] == "orange"].nunique().stale == 1 & df.loc[df["typee"] == "orange"].nunique().stock == 1
```

Comment: this would not work since it will not take in account that there are groups of `types`

Answer (score 0):

Can groupby size twice. The first collapses to unique combinations, the second checks if there is only one per type.

```
df.groupby([*df]).size().groupby('type').size().eq(1)
#type
#apple     True
#orange    True
#dtype: bool
```